# Android Context Passing on doInBackground

Tags: android

I sent "Scores Activity" to doinbackground then run a function on Scores Activity but getting
"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." on "birinci.setText(txt);" line.

what am I missing here looks using same context?

```
Scores Activity
{
Object[] stuff = {this.dhn, Scores.this};
ConnectXML runXML = new ConnectXML();
runXML.execute(stuff);
}

public void setScoreListUpdate(String txt)
{
birinci.setText(txt);
}



private Scores myScores;
protected String doInBackground(Object... arguments) {

myScores = (Scores)stuff[1];
myScores.setScoreListUpdate(result);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message already gives the answer: you can't touch (edit/modify/update/etc.) any views from a thread that did not create them. Since anything that is executed in the `doInBackgrund(...)` of an AsyncTask is done by a separate thread, you can't do any direct view manipulations in there.

The solution is quite simple: override the other methods an AsyncTask provides, depending on your needs. If you're trying to update a view after all work is done, simply override `onPostExecute(...)`. If you want to indicate some sort of progress while the work is being done in the background, use `onProgressUpdate(...)`. Everything in there is being executed by the main UI thread (which created all views).

Please have read through the [documentation on AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), since that describes the different steps and possibilities quite clearly.

Comment: yep my mistake! I put myScores.setScoreListUpdate(result);
on postExecute Its worked fine. thanks for your help